# What screen should show after closing an iframe/modal?

Tags: modal-windows, modal

I have a challenge of what I should display after a user has triggered an iFrame modal which changes the meaning of the page that it was triggered from.

My assumption is that users would expect a modal is to return to the screen in it's original state after it's closed, but in my case the original screen is redundant after the function within the iFrame is complete.

What would you do to tackle this problem? Turning the iframe into a page is not an option, it must remain a modal.

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your modal actions (more information would be useful), there are quite a few things that could be done after the modal is closed and the original page is supposedly deprecated:

- Remove the modal triggering button and change the message of the screen
- Provide a link or button for users to move on/redirect them to
  another page
- Redirect users to another/next page in the workflow (could even include few seconds countdown for redirection)
- Redirect users to previous page (depends on what the page+modal were
  for)
- Make the modal a big popover in the first place (depends on the
  amount of content)
- Display a summary of the actions performed in the modal on the modal-trigger page and allow users to go to another page (provide redirection link)
  etc

TLDR, if the page becomes deprecated it is a good idea to either

- immediately **move users to a new page**, or to
- **provide with a link/option to move to another page**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: great! let me know if it's the accepted answer -- I'd like to link this one :)